# how to show text rotate using css?

Tags: html, css, design-patterns

I have the following issues:
 - I want to rotate text as shown in image 
 - Here, I am trying to do this in the following code
Can anyone please provide me with a solution?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top:20px;
}

div#myDiv {
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  transform: rotate(315deg); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">
This div element is rotated .
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
This div element is rotated .
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
This div element is rotated .
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**I want to set text like "demo text" as shown in the image**:

[image: i want set text like "demo text" show in image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `display: inline-block` on your divs and set the `transform-origin` to right.

See example below:

```css
div#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block; /* add display: inline-block */
}

div#myDiv {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  This div element is rotated .
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  This div element is rotated .
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  This div element is rotated .
</div>
```

Comment: you can set `transform-origin: right;` and remove the tanslation .. we also no more need the prefixes for transform

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah, I like that idea of transforming the origin. Thanks for that, I've update my answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to rotate text. It is responsive for all devices.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  margin: 4rem auto;
}

div#myDiv {
  background-color: black;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="myDiv">
      Demo Text
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
      Demo Text
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
      Demo Text
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
      Demo Text
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
      Demo Text
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all giving same id to more than one html element is invalid. I replaced that with the class and used the corresponding selector in the css as well and added more styles there.

Try this:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.myDiv {
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  display: inline !important;
  float: left;
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  This div element is rotated .
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  This div element is rotated .
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  This div element is rotated .
</div>
```

Comment: thanks to replay but how to remove space between two div ?

Comment: Reduce the width of class myDiv as much as you can

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use flex for more dynamic nature of your code
If u want to build something exactly the way in the image u have shared then,
first enclose your elements into a container

```
<div class="container">

elem 1

elem 2

elem 3

</div>
```

where container will have `display flex`

flex direction will be **row**
create a grid if u want to ease out your work,
u can use **bootstrap 4 grid** as well its flex based

once grid is set place you elements and transform rotate to whatever angle you want,
that should be the approach
flex will place ur elements and also smoothly(default animation) re-arrange when screen is resized with just few lines of code..
try to work around and update.
Hope this will guide you